# Changing the itemize marker location in Context

Tags: context, context-mkiv

When manually defining the itemize marker with Metapost, the location of the marker appears to be quite low (see picture, the pink line added to highlight the problem). It looks rather ugly, and I'd like to move it a little upwards.
[image: The triangle position could be better!]

```
\startuseMPgraphic{itemize:triangle}
  save p; path p;
  p := ( (0,-0.5) --(0,0.5)--(0.5,0)--cycle ) scaled ExHeight;
  fill p withcolor red;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definesymbol[itemize:main][\useMPgraphic{itemize:triangle}]
\setupitemize[1][symbol=itemize:main]

\starttext

\startitemize
    \startitem
        The triangle position could be better!
    \stopitem
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

Comment: You can move the symbol upwards with the `\offset` command: `\definesymbol[itemize:main][{\offset[bottomoffset=.25ex]{\useMPgraphic{itemize:triangle}}}]`

Answer (score 1):

To align the itemize symbol in the middle of the line, you could use the plain-TeX-inherited `\vcenter`.

```
\startuseMPgraphic{itemize:triangle}
  save p; path p;
  p := ( (0,-0.5) --(0,0.5)--(0.5,0)--cycle ) scaled ExHeight;
  fill p withcolor red;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definesymbol[itemize:main][\vcenter{\hbox{\useMPgraphic{itemize:triangle}}}]
\setupitemize[1][symbol=itemize:main]

\starttext
\startitemize
  \startitem
    The triangle position could be better!
  \stopitem
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

[image]